# Problem with link in responsive menu (go to undefinied url)

Tags: magento2, menu, rwd

I'm facing a pretty ugly issue. When I'm on desktop, no problem with the menu link.

When I'm on responsive, when I go through the menu, I have the right URL but when I press the item, I'm redirected to a 404 page ( my.url/undefined)

But I have no problem on responsive when I do "Click Right" -> "Open in new tab"

Does anyone faced this issue ?

Answer (score 6):

If anyone has this issue, my problem was that I have a custom menu and the file **menu.js** of magento looks for **.ui-menu-item** class (so basicaly I've added this class to my menu items)

Comment: yes, I had this issue in custom menu. after add those class that is fixed. Thanks!